# Passing complex information via COM to C# from Delphi code

Tags: c#, delphi, com

For various reasons, such as protecting investment, etc. I need to pass a series of complex records (numerous fields and records) back and forth between Delphi and a C# program. I guess I should be using IEnumVariant, but don't seem to able to design this with the typelibrary designer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**Update**

I guess what I am trying to ask needs some explanation of the complexity of the data.

I need to export to C# (or any other language really), via COM a collection of 'records', each made up of a collection of 'fields', each made up of a number of attributes.

So it is a collection of a collection of a collection! Don't ask me how we got here, we just have.

So I'm have Attribute -> Field -> Record sort of structure.  I have a grasp of what I need to export (I can't post any details here for company reasons), but don't know how to start to export that data in COM.

Probably I should start by creating a test program from scratch which will mimic the structures I need, and then gradually COMize them and see where I get to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question!

I created a series of classes that dessended from IEnumVARIANT, representing the different collections of bits of data, the list and the record. Each fields was a simple COM interface definition.

I used examples from [this location](http://www.gekko-software.nl/Delphi/demo_application.htm), as I implement the collections of fields / records / etc as TList.

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulate the info in classes.  Works well in any language, works well in COM too.

Comment: Except C# knows nothing about Delphi classes, and vice versa. You didn't answer the OP's question at all - the question was "how to pass complex information via COM between C# and Delphi code?". Saying "use classes" doesn't help.

Comment: It does.  Anything else is problematic.  COM doesn't support structures well because their layout is so compiler dependent.  Mapping a class isn't a problem, properties and methods map to a COM interface.  That's glue that's built into both .NET and Delphi.